# Weird PHP "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare" Error

Tags: php, mysql, function

My script is returning the following error...

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare connecttodatabase() (previously declared in /var/www/api/connecttodatabase.php:4) in /var/www/api/connecttodatabase.php on line 6
```

And the following is the connecttodatabase.php file...

```
<?php
    function connecttodatabase()
    {
        $con = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "name", "password", "database");
        return $con;
    }
?>
```

I don't really understand this error because line 6 is just the closed curly bracket (})

I think the error means that it thinks I declared the function `connecttodatabase()` in to different spots but clearly I didn't.

Comment: You have that function declared twice. You probably are including the same file where it is defined twice.

Comment: why don't you change the name of function and confirm . did you?

Comment: The error says you're attempting to re-declare a function on line 6 that's already declared on line 4. Is what you've posted your **complete** code? We can't help you without knowing more about your problem.

Comment: It means you've already a function named `connecttodatabase()`, change function name or remove included/required file.

Comment: @esqew Yes, this is my complete code

Comment: In English: `include('/var/www/api/connecttodatabase.php');` was declared somewhere (magic), `function connecttodatabase(){}` is in that file, you are trying to create another function with the same name. If the code you posted is a view file then a controller file probably included the file.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I know that but I am not creating any other functions anywhere with that same name...

Comment: If you rename your function to `connecttodatabasee` then do you get the same message?

Comment: You're calling `connecttodatabase()` from somewhere (and/or from somewhere else also), otherwise it wouldn't fire up. Show us the code where you are calling the function.

Comment: @Fred-ii- If I'm understanding you correctly this error is being throw because I am calling, `$con = connecttodatabase();` then later in the same script I am calling `$con2 = connecttodatabase();`. That would be the issue?

Comment: Are you including/requiring the file connecttodatabase.php in two places? (sorry, just realized this is the same comment as John Conde, I upvoted his)

Comment: I would say so, yes. If you're using it as an include/require then try using `include_once` or `require_once`

Comment: @RamondelaFuente Yes, I will change to require_once

Comment: It's best at this point to show full code and its usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, this is most likely because you have included connecttodatabase.php twice in your code, and you are certainly defining the function twice. Don't get hung up why it's line 6; line 2 would be more helpful, but line 6 is where the function definition *ends*, and so arguably *is* when the function is defined. You could have a "one a day" whole year calendar on the idiosyncrasies of PHP and have enough left over for a sequel. As others have also hinted, some basic debugging would confirm whether you are including the file more than once and also from where.

Make sure that your code uses include_once or require_once.

Comment: I changed all my code to `require_once` yet the issue is still prevalent. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Basic debugging skills would suggest to try logging a backtrace at the start of the file to see from where it is being included. Renaming the function would also be a useful test as has already been mentioned.

Comment: @JakeGould But that just returns that one time in connecttodatabase.php, the issue is I am using `require_once('connecttodatabase.php')` multiple times in the same file.

Comment: @JakeGould what you are describing is a static analaysis, which gives no clues about runtime behavior. 'grep -r' is a great friend, and might solve for this one, but runtime behaviour could be more useful. But if he really has a code duplicate, then sure, that should catch it.

Comment: Missed one `require_once` in a file I forgot I was using it in. The issue is fixed. Thanks mate.

Comment: @user3558410 *"the issue is I am using require_once('connecttodatabase.php') multiple times in the same file."* - why were you doing that? Had you posted your full code to start with, would have avoided all this.